# Is it possible to include a formula within IMPORTHTML?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this Google sheet where 2 columns are present.
Based on a drop down (of list of first column), I have used a vloopup to find corresponding values in second column. Straightforward.

However, when i reference the column containing vlookup formula in an IMPORTHTML statement, it doesn't give me results.

Any clues on how to fix this?

`IMPORTHTML("https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/fnoquote/""&AB5""/""&AC5""/""&A1""","table",6)`

Here AB5 is the drop down cell and AC5 is the cell containing vlookup.
I realize AC5 is the issue as there is no error if I input the value manually.

[Screenshot of my Google sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRFqi.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are that no quotes are required in the URL. Try this:

```
=importhtml("https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/fnoquote/" & AB5 & "/" & AC5 & "/" & A1, "table", 6)
```